# UML. The difference between black box and white box in the component diagram

Tags: uml

Is it only the difference between the black box and the white one that only interfaces can be specified for the first, while for the second we can display the internal structure?
[image]
On the diagram I showed my vision of the differences in the boxes. Is it correct?
[image]

Comment: No time to check now, but shouldn't the arrow for required interface be in the opposite direction?

Comment: @Ister Not for delegation. I just checked the specs due to a related question and they just use (now?) un-stereotyped un-directed lines for delegation. It seems that they got influenced quite a bit by SysML in this part of the specs.

Comment: @Ister Found it in 2.1.1 on p. 153. You're right with the direction. But as said, they now use a plain line for delegation.

Comment: The first diagram shows that Class1 and Class2 realize Component WhiteBox. The second shows Connectors inside WhiteBox. This is only possible in a Composite Structure Diagram, which can be shown in a compartment, but needs to have a line separating it from he name. The parts then should have a leading colon, to separate the role (empty here) and the type. Finally a connector is only possible between parts or ports. Therefore, Class1 needs to have two ports. The connector may be shown connected to the Interface, but in fact it will be connected to the port. It doesn’t have arrows or stereotype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A black box is, as the name says, black inside. You can't see what is inside. In contrast a white box shows anything inside. It depends on the use case which one to prefer.

You often get a black box when you buy a product from a company. They hide what exactly is inside and how they made it. Open source in contrast is a white box.

Notably your white box isn't all that white. It's more grey. You don't see which part is responsible for which interface.

Please also note that the terms black/white box are not UML terms but were born a long time before anyone thought of UML or objects. See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box

Comment: added second diagram.. Is it a real white box now?

Comment: Yes. That looks like one :-)

Answer (score 3):

Every component can be drawn either as a black box or as a white box. If you draw a component as a black box, you don't show its internals, only its interface(s). If you draw the same component as a white box, you do show its internals.

Both diagrams are valid UML diagrams. In the first diagram, only little information is given about the internals of `White Box`, so you might say that it is not a pure white box, but there is no strict definition of 'white box'.

Comment: and second a "pure" one?

Comment: Second shows how those interfaces are actually handled internally so it is "purer". As www.admiraalit.nl mentioned there is no such thing as a precise white-box definition. The more details you give the "whiter" it becomes. On the other hand you never give all details just like you never model all aspects of a model - that's why we call it a model.